# Making a horizental scroll area for the mobiles in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create a horizental scroll area for the mobiles . and i want to it be like this :
[image]

And i wnat to hide the scrollbar also too .

I tried this but there is a problem whith that and i cant give them width !

```
      <div style="overflow: auto hidden; display: flex;" id="v">
        <div>
          <img src="url" style="width: 100%; height: 20%;" alt="">
          <p>name</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe helps. Using `overflow: auto;`

```css
#carousel {
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    
    overflow: auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

#carousel .slide {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel">
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150"/>
    </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150"/>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the scrollbar horizental

```
.container {
    overflow: auto hidden;
};
```

To hide the scrollbar use:

```
.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
     display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi well its true but my problem is something else . when I try to make divs for them!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).